# Crop an Image with an angle in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, image-processing, crop

I have an Image of 400 x 300 pixels. I want to crop a portion of the image with 200 X 100 pixels but with an angle say 30 degree.

Please check the image for easier understanding...

[image: Crop image like this]

What I have tried so far.

```
private var mInputImage: UIImage = UIImage(named: "Z01")! //say 400 x 300 pixel
let croppingRect = CGRect(x: 50, y: 100, width: 200, height: 100)

let cgImage = mInputImage.cgImage! 
let croppedCGImage = cgImage.cropping(to: croppingRect)
```

But how can I crop it with 30 degree angle?

Comment: You can’t. What you need is an alpha channel

Comment: Another option is to rotate the image before cropping it.

Comment: How should the resulting image look like? Should it be rotated such that it aligns with the x and y axes? Or should it still have the tilt angle?

Comment: @Codo I want it to be rotated such that it aligns with the x and y

Comment: @Joya Roy I added solution. If it is helpful please vote my answer or your problem is still continue please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

`cgImage.cropping()` doesn't support an angle. Here is a different solution using a mask:

```
func croppingRectWithAngle(cgRect: CGRect, degree: CGFloat)->CAShapeLayer{
    let angle = degree * .pi / 180
    let path = UIBezierPath()
    let width = cgRect.width
    let height = cgRect.height
    let center = CGPoint(x: cgRect.origin.x+cgRect.width/2, y: cgRect.origin.y+cgRect.height/2)
    
    let topLeftPoint     = CGPoint(x: center.x - ((width / 2) * cos(angle)) - ((height / 2) * sin(angle)),
                               y: center.y - ((width / 2) * sin(angle)) + ((height / 2) * cos(angle)))
    let topRightPoint    = CGPoint(x: center.x + ((width / 2) * cos(angle)) - ((height / 2) * sin(angle)),
                               y: center.y + ((width / 2) * sin(angle)) + ((height / 2) * cos(angle)))
    let bottomLeftPoint  = CGPoint(x: center.x - ((width / 2) * cos(angle)) + ((height / 2) * sin(angle)),
                               y: center.y - ((width / 2) * sin(angle)) - ((height / 2) * cos(angle)))
    let bottomRightPoint = CGPoint(x: center.x + ((width / 2) * cos(angle)) + ((height / 2) * sin(angle)),
                               y: center.y + ((width / 2) * sin(angle)) - ((height / 2) * cos(angle)))
    
    
    path.move(to: topLeftPoint)
    path.addLine(to: topRightPoint)
    path.addLine(to: bottomRightPoint)
    path.addLine(to: bottomLeftPoint)
    
    path.close()
    let mask = CAShapeLayer()
    mask.path = path.cgPath
    return mask
}
```

Example Usage:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let image = UIImage(named: "example")! //say 400 x 300 pixel
    
    let inputImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 400, height: 300))
    inputImageView.image = image
    
    let croppingImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 500, width: 400, height: 300))
    croppingImageView.image = image
    
    croppingImageView.layer.mask = croppingRectWithAngle(cgRect: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 200, height: 100), degree: 45.0)

    self.view.addSubview(inputImageView)
    self.view.addSubview(croppingImageView)
}
```

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: You can add this code `croppingImageView.transform = croppingImageView.transform.rotated(by: -45.0 * .pi / 180)` before addSubView.